# How to visualize the trajectory of the robot arm in Rviz, when the Cartesian velocity command is passed?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What should I do to visualise it in Rviz?  geometry_msgs/TwistStamped is used

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279581/how-to-visualize-the-trajectory-of-the-robot-arm-in-rviz,-when-the-cartesian-velocity-command-is-passed?/) by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2018-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @pmuthu2s,

I've seen that you've tried to see it using  Markers in RViz in your [another question](https://answers.ros.org/question/279558/visualising-the-real-time-trajectory-path-using-markers/).

By checking the answer in that question we can see that the Markers work, but you have to select the right `frame_id` when publishing it.

Also, you have to make sure you are really receiving the messages of type `geometry_msgs/TwistStamped`. You can do that with `rostopic echo /TOPIC_THAT_PUBLISHES_TWISTSTAMPED_MESSAGE`

Please, that a look in the [answer of that your another question](https://answers.ros.org/question/279558/visualising-the-real-time-trajectory-path-using-markers/?answer=279739#post-id-279739).

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2018-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1